# Ensuring that list images are never truncated on the left

Tags: html, css, webkit

I want to ensure that my list images (i.e., bullet symbols for unordered lists and numbers/letters/etc. for ordered lists) never truncate on the left, regardless of the font size they use.  This seems to be an issue for WebKit-based browsers and I'm not sure of a decent workaround.

For example, the following piece of HTML displays improperly with Chrome 8/9:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ol style="font-size: 48px;">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

The same piece of HTML displays properly (i.e., it doesn't truncate on the left) in Internet Explorer 8.

Two (undesirable) workarounds I've discovered are:

1. Specify `list-style-position: inside;` on the list.  This forces the list image to flow with the content, but it makes for a non-standard/messy look, IMO.
2. Specify some type of margin/padding on the list.  This works, but then it adds too much padding to lists with smaller font sizes.

Here's a screenshot that shows the problem in Chrome 9.0.597.98; note how the numbers are cut off on the left margin:

[image: Chrome 9 list image bug]

Comment: Can you post screenshots? I've tested in Opera 11, Chrome 9 and FF4 all look fine

Comment: I've attached a screenshot showing the problem in Chrome 9.  I'm surprised that you weren't able to reproduce the problem with that browser in particular, since I think that any WebKit-based browsers will exhibit this issue when loading that piece of HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see your problem in Chrome 9 and the latest Safari on OSX. You can try specifying the margins in `em`s to get them to scale with the `font-size`, this produce reasonable results for me:

```
ol { margin-left: 0.5em; }
li { margin-left: 0; }
```

but YMMV of course. Your best bet is to use a class on the `<ol>` to keep the `font-size` and `margin-left` together, then you can tweak them together to get reasonable results in the various browsers.

This isn't a perfect solution but going for pixel-identical results in multiple browsers and on multiple operating systems is not only frustrating and often impossible but also a bit pointless (IMHO).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I think your approach comes closest to what I'm trying to achieve, although all of the answers have given me some food for thought.

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<style>
#big {font-size:48px;}
#little {font-size:12px;}
ol { padding:0; margin:0; }
li  { margin:0 0 0 96px; padding:0 0 0 14px; }
</style>
  <body>
    <ol id="big">
      <li>one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one </li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="little">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: But if one of the `<li>`s wraps to a second line it will wrap under the list marker and the asker doesn't like that appearance.

Comment: @mu - You're right. I edited my original post to address wrapping. The screen shot is from Safari OSX. IE does a better job of aligning the 48px and 12px to the decimal, but some tinkering with a support class on the small text could fix that.

Comment: I checked with Safari OSX and the 48px version was clipping the list markers on the left side. Adding `margin-left` to the list or the items sorts that problem out, which element gets the `margin-left` depends on which appearance you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set margin / padding for your lists ?

Browsers may have different "default" styles for UL and OL elements.

It is often usefull to apply "reset" style rules and/or specify the styles you want to be applied to common elements such as lists, paragraphs, blockquotes, tables, headings,...

see here for basic CSS resets : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/